# @ViewScoped works in development mode, but does not in production mode

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2

this code always throws ViewExpiredException

```
@ManagedBean(name = "test")
@ViewScoped
public class test implements Serializable{

    private int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void increment() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

and xhtml:

```
<body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputText value="Counter: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{test.count}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="Count" action="#{test.increment}" update="@form" />
    </h:form>
</body>
```

there some trick?
the session is stored in server

Comment: try adding `private static final long serialVersionUID = ...` to your bean... (also you better use `<h:body>` in JSF instead of <body>) , also try `<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>` ?

Comment: with serialVersionUID the same exception,<param-value>client</param-value> is the solution, but i'm trying with <param-value>server</param-value>

Comment: @mulax do you have `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>` in your *appengine-web.xml* ? also , what GAE SDK are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your *GAE SDK* version... but at least with older versions one had to set `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `client` cause *GAE* was not supporting it set to `session`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: For several months I have it set so, hoping someone has found a way to run with <param-value>server</param-value>.
thanks well, if no one answers, I will mark as correct answer

Comment: Try setting it to server without View scoped beans , see if it works... take a look at this article(haven't read it , but noticed the using the `server` settings) http://javamomentum.be/2011/04/google-app-engine-with-jsf2-cdi/ ...

Comment: SessionScoped woks in development and production mode. ViewScoped only in development mode